# How to get call duration of twilio browser to browser call confrence?

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio api for browser to browser confrence calling through java. Now I want to get the Browser call duration. Is there any way to get the call duration or I have to record the confrence?
   My twiml is here

```
TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
    Dial dial = new Dial();
    dial.setHangupOnStar(true);
     //Conference will be named room.
     Conference conf = new Conference(room);
     conf.setBeep(Conference.BEEP_TRUE);
     try {
            dial.append(conf);
            twiml.append(dial);
        } catch (TwiMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 twiml.toXML();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It looks like you are accepting an inbound call (possibly from an instance of Twilio Client) and then using TwiML to direct that incoming call into a conference.  Am I reading your code correctly?

If I am, then you can use a [StatusCallback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#asynchronous) to have Twilio tell you when that inbound call ends.  This HTTP request will include a parameter named `CallDuration` that is the length of the completed call in seconds.

If the inbound call is coming to a Twilio phone number, you can configure that number with a StatusCallback URL by opening the phone number properties in the Developer Console:

[image]

If the incoming call is coming from an instance of Twilio Client, you can configure your TwiML App with a StatusCallback URL by opening the TwiML App properties and expanding its Optional Settings:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: by CallDuration parameter, I am getting the duration of conference call even when a single participant enter into conference room. Is there any way  to get the duration when at least two participant enters into conference room?

Comment: I don't beleive there is anything that Twilio provides that will tell you the time that at least two people are in a conference.  You could certainly create that yourself by storing a timestamp in your application when you direct a second call into a conference.